# How can I use hover on one element to change the background of the whole page in CSS, Javascript and/or HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background image when the "euro" button is hovered on, any help would be greatly appreciated

Relevant code (this failed):

```css
#body:hover > #euro{
        background: url(https://media.hswstatic.com/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjb250ZW50Lmhzd3N0YXRpYy5jb20iLCJrZXkiOiJnaWZcL2V1cm9zLmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7InJlc2l6ZSI6eyJ3aWR0aCI6ODI4fX19);   
    }
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div id="container">
    <h3>Calculator</h3>
    Dollars:<br>
    <input type="number" id="num1"><br> Forgein Currency:<br>
    <input type="number" id="ans" readonly><br>
    <br><br>
    <button id="euro">£</button>
    <button id="yen">¥</button>
    <button id="rupee">₹</button>
    <button id="mexpes">MX$</button>
    <button id="clear">C</button>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you want to change the background image of the `body` when `#euro` is hovered?

Comment: yeah I think that's what im going for

Comment: sorry im a bit of a noob

Comment: Please, Java is NOT JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pure HTML + CSS implementation**

```css
#euro:hover~#bg {
  
        background-image: url("https://media.hswstatic.com/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjb250ZW50Lmhzd3N0YXRpYy5jb20iLCJrZXkiOiJnaWZcL2V1cm9zLmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7InJlc2l6ZSI6eyJ3aWR0aCI6ODI4fX19");
}

#bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  widht: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h3>Calculator</h3>
    Dollars:<br>
    <input type="number" id="num1"><br> Foreign Currency:<br>
    <input type="number" id="ans" readonly><br>
    <br><br>
    <button id="euro">£</button>
    <button id="yen">¥</button>
    <button id="rupee">₹</button>
    <button id="mexpes">MX$</button>
    <button id="clear">C</button>
    <div id="bg">
    </div>



  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: This is the British Pound, not the Euro sign. ;-) The sign for Euro is €.

Comment: I did not edit the content of the parts of code I thought was irrelevant to the question, which is the logic to change `body` styling on hover of another element.

Comment: Of course. I just did a backseat-driver statement. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

using javascript

```
euro.onmouseover = () => {
  document.body.style.background = 'url(https://media.hswstatic.com/eyJidWNrZXQiOiJjb250ZW50Lmhzd3N0YXRpYy5jb20iLCJrZXkiOiJnaWZcL2V1cm9zLmpwZyIsImVkaXRzIjp7InJlc2l6ZSI6eyJ3aWR0aCI6ODI4fX19)';
}

euro.onmouseleave = () => {
  document.body.style.background = 'white';
}
```